# value inside the array should be replaced

Tags: php

This is the array given

```
$arr = array(',12,10',',9,10');
```

I want to remove the first blank element from the starting and the new array should be

```
$arr = array('12,10','9,10');
```

Comment: `array_map(function ($s) { return ltrim($s, ','); }, $arr)`…?!

Comment: thank you  , it is working fine fine now  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) or [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
array_map(function ($s) { return ltrim($s, ','); }, $arr);
```

Or

```
array_map(function ($s) { return trim($s, ','); }, $arr);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/941395

Note:- `trim()` will remove leading and trailing extra comma from each array element

Comment: The array is 

$arr = array(array('id'=>1,'agent_id'=>',12,10'),array('id'=>1,'agent_id'=>',12,10'));

    $agent_id= 12;

I want to compare the agent_id value to the agent_id string in the array and return the respective id in another array .


    $id_found = array('1','2'); 

How can i do it?

Comment: @SanjitBhardwaj  please ask a new question for that. Address me the link and i will try to answer,otherwise you will get answer for-sure